# Update/Create rows in a SQL Server table based on data from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL Server tables. One table has four `nvarchar(50)` nullable columns and an `ID` column. The second table has two columns: `ID`, `nvarchar(50)` nullable column

I'm trying to insert the rows in the second table into the first table. How can I detect a null column in the first table and insert data from the second one into the null cell?

Ex:

Add from the second table

```
1   value3
```

to the first table

```
1     value1   value2   null    null
```

so the resulting row is

```
1     value1   value2   value3   null
```

Ex2:

Add from the second table

```
2   value1
```

to the first table

```
nothing for ID 2
```

so the resulting row is

```
2     value1   null   null   null
```

Basically I need to update existing rows or create new ones depending on the ID of the second table rows.

Comment: Check out the MERGE statement.

Comment: The problem I see is that depending on the data in the first table, the data from the second table is inserted into different columns... this will be very tricky to get right. If you would be updating the **same** columns with the data from your second table, then it's a piece of cake....

Comment: It seems like you placed in different columns what belonged to different rows. Is it possible to modify the database schema instead?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the data could be inserted into any column, which makes things more difficult.

Comment: @Laurent' Anything is fair game. The second table is a normalized version of the first one. The task is to insert data from one to the another.

Comment: What PKs,AKs and FKs do you have in these two tables ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: Please forgive me my ignorance (or dumbness) but what's `AK`?

Comment: @AndriyM - No problem. AK = [alternate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Alternate_key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @T1 table
(
  ID int primary key,
  C1 varchar(50),
  C2 varchar(50),
  C3 varchar(50),
  C4 varchar(50)
);

declare @T2 table
(
  ID int primary key,
  C varchar(50)  
);

insert into @T1 values (1, 'value1', 'value2', null, null) ;

insert into @T2 values (1, 'value3');
insert into @T2 values (2, 'value1');

merge @T1 as T1
using @T2 as T2
on T1.ID = T2.ID
when not matched then
  insert (ID, C1)  values (T2.ID, T2.C)
when matched then
  update set
    C1 = case when T1.C1 is null 
           then T2.C 
           else T1.C1 
         end,
    C2 = case when T1.C1 is not null and 
                   T1.C2 is null 
           then T2.C 
           else T1.C2 
         end,
    C3 = case when T1.C1 is not null and 
                   T1.C2 is not null and 
                   T1.C3 is null 
           then T2.C 
           else T1.C3 
         end,
    C4 = case when T1.C1 is not null and 
                   T1.C2 is not null and 
                   T1.C3 is not null and 
                   T1.C4 is null 
           then T2.C 
           else T1.C4 
         end
;

select *
from @T1;
```

Result:

```
ID C1     C2     C3     C4
-- ------ ------ ------ ------
1  value1 value2 value3 NULL
2  value1 NULL   NULL   NULL
```

Comment: Good answer, but it won't work if there are two rows in `T2` for the same `ID` value (which I'd assume is a possibility from the problem statement)(even if the PK is removed from `T2`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True. That's why I declare ID in `@T2` as primary key. Also from a comment in the question "The second table is a normalized version of the first one" makes me assume that ID is the PK in the second table.

Comment: I drew the opposite conclusion - I'd expect `T2` to contain 4 rows with the same `ID` value, and each of the `C1` - `C4` values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another try. I'm completely changing your architecture here but you still might find it usefull.

### Unsorted Value Set

For this answer I'm assuming that the column order is NOT important (you're basically storing  a set of values in them). I think a better architecture for *this* is to store each value on a different row. This make querying and modifying much easier (hence my comment on your question).

What  I would do in this case is to create a new table that looks like this:

```
ID    ValueSet
1     value1
1     value2
1     value3
2     value1
```

To transform your two tables into this one, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID,C1 AS `ValueSet` FROM `tab1` WHERE C1 IS NOT NULL
   UNION SELECT ID,C2 FROM `tab1` WHERE C2 IS NOT NULL
   UNION SELECT ID,C3 FROM `tab1` WHERE C3 IS NOT NULL
   UNION SELECT ID,C4 FROM `tab1` WHERE C4 IS NOT NULL
   UNION SELECT ID,C1 FROM `tab2` WHERE C1 IS NOT NULL
```

This way NULL values are removed and tab2 values are gracefully added whenever needed.

Again, note that you loose the  column order here.

### Sorted Value Set

If order is important, you still can include at creation using this modified query:

```
SELECT ID,C1 AS `ValueSet`,'1' AS 'Order'  FROM `tab1` WHERE C1 IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT ID,C2,'2' FROM `tab1` WHERE C2 IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT ID,C3,'3' FROM `tab1` WHERE C3 IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT ID,C4,'4' FROM `tab1` WHERE C4 IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT ID,C1,'5' FROM `tab2` WHERE C1 IS NOT NULL
```

Then, if you need the sorted valueset for ID 1, you can use:

```
SELECT ValueSet FROM `myNewTable` WHERE ID = '1' ORDER BY Order ASC;
```

which will yield:

```
value1
value2
value3
```